# Analyzing cProcess output

Tags: python, cprofile

I have a python script that analyzes an output of a Perforce server. With this I have two different ways to output the what processes are running at a given time.

**1.Matching process indents with start of process indent (P120 would have 119 indents)**

`+P1
     +P2
-P1
           +P3
           -P3
     -P2`

**2.Matching process indents with the number of processes running**

`+P1
     +P2
         +P3
         -P2
     -P3
-P1`

For both of these functions the input is a list of process object that I have created.

***Code for type 1: (SLOW)***

```
def visual_output_match(processes):

output_string = ""
process_number = 1
indent_number = 0
running_processes = []

# Go through each process
for process in processes:
    # Assign a process number to the new process that is about to start
    process.set_process_number(process_number)

    # This will append the process onto a list of processes that are currently running
    running_processes.append(process)

    # Get a list of processes that have ended before the new process started
    ending_processes = check_ended_processes(running_processes, process)

    # Delete the processes that have ended from the running_processes list
    running_processes = remove_running_processes(running_processes, ending_processes)

    # Print all the processes that finished before the new process began
    for p in ending_processes:
        # Tabs over the correct amount depending on how many processes are running
        indent_number = p.get_process_number() - 1
        output_string += ('\t' * indent_number)
        output_string += ("-P" + str(p.get_process_number()) + "   " + p.short_srting_summary_end() + '\n')

    # Tabs over the correct amount depending on how many processes are running
    indent_number = process.get_process_number() - 1
    output_string += ('\t' * indent_number)
    output_string += ("+P" + str(process.get_process_number()) + "   " + process.short_srting_summary_start() + '\n')
    process_number += 1
return output_string`
```

***Code for type 2: (FAST)***

```
def visual_output_not_match(processes):

output_string = ""
number_tabs = 0
process_number = 1
running_processes = []

# Go through each process
for process in processes:
    # Assign a process number to the new process that is about to start
    process.set_process_number(process_number)

    # This will append the process onto a list of processes that are currently running
    running_processes.append(process)

    # Get a list of processes that have ended before the new process started
    ending_processes = check_ended_processes(running_processes, process)

    # Delete the processes that have ended from the running_processes list
    running_processes = remove_running_processes(running_processes, ending_processes)

    # Print all the processes that finished before the new process began
    for p in ending_processes:
        number_tabs -= 1
        # Tabs over the correct amount depending on how many processes are running
        output_string += ('\t' * number_tabs)
        output_string += ("-P" + str(p.get_process_number()) + "   " + p.short_srting_summary_end() + '\n')

    # Tabs over the correct amount depending on how many processes are running
    output_string += ("\t" * number_tabs)
    output_string += ("+P" + str(process.get_process_number()) + "   " + process.short_srting_summary_start() + '\n')
    number_tabs += 1
    process_number += 1
return output_string
```

For the exact some number of processes the 1st type will take upwards of 11 minutes while the other one will only take around 1 second. Now I realize that with type 1 if I have 11,000 processes then I will at some point have 11,000 tabs on a given line and with type 2 that is not true. Although would that be the only thing that is slowing my script down? Does anyone else see any other critical errors. Let me know if you need to see some of the other methods that I call in this script.

Now I did run a cProfiler on these two functions and this is what I get:

***1: (SLOW)***

```
     3381490 function calls in 681.195 seconds

     Ordered by: internal time

     ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
          1  679.175  679.175  681.182  681.182 visual_output.py:107(visual_output_match)
      13706    0.568    0.000    0.769    0.000 visual_output.py:147(check_ended_processes)
      13706    0.404    0.000    0.657    0.000 visual_output.py:162(remove_running_processes)
      13706    0.258    0.000    0.264    0.000 server_info.py:398(short_srting_summary_start)
      13702    0.257    0.000    0.264    0.000 server_info.py:402(short_srting_summary_end)
     787125    0.206    0.000    0.206    0.000 server_info.py:67(__eq__)
     800837    0.118    0.000    0.118    0.000 server_info.py:267(get_datetime_end)
     800837    0.080    0.000    0.080    0.000 server_info.py:264(get_datetime_start)
     800828    0.038    0.000    0.038    0.000 {len}
      54816    0.028    0.000    0.028    0.000 server_info.py:308(get_process_number)
      13706    0.018    0.000    0.018    0.000 server_info.py:406(set_process_number)
          1    0.013    0.013  681.195  681.195 <string>:1(<module>)
      27408    0.013    0.000    0.013    0.000 {method 'time' of 'datetime.datetime' objects}
      27408    0.011    0.000    0.011    0.000 {method 'append' of 'list' objects}
      13702    0.010    0.000    0.010    0.000 {method 'pop' of 'list' objects}
          1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
```

***2: (FAST)***

```
           3354269 function calls (3354219 primitive calls) in 1.981 seconds

     Ordered by: internal time

     ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
          1    0.688    0.688    1.981    1.981 visual_output.py:67(visual_output_not_match)
      13706    0.407    0.000    0.563    0.000 visual_output.py:147(check_ended_processes)
      13706    0.375    0.000    0.603    0.000 visual_output.py:162(remove_running_processes)
     787125    0.189    0.000    0.189    0.000 server_info.py:67(__eq__)
     800837    0.079    0.000    0.079    0.000 server_info.py:267(get_datetime_end)
     800837    0.075    0.000    0.075    0.000 server_info.py:264(get_datetime_start)
      13706    0.059    0.000    0.061    0.000 server_info.py:398(short_srting_summary_start)
      13702    0.053    0.000    0.055    0.000 server_info.py:402(short_srting_summary_end)
     800850    0.035    0.000    0.035    0.000 {len}
      13706    0.005    0.000    0.005    0.000 server_info.py:406(set_process_number)
      27408    0.005    0.000    0.005    0.000 server_info.py:308(get_process_number)
      13702    0.004    0.000    0.004    0.000 {method 'pop' of 'list' objects}
      27434    0.003    0.000    0.003    0.000 {method 'append' of 'list' objects}
      27408    0.003    0.000    0.003    0.000 {method 'time' of 'datetime.datetime' objects}
          1    0.000    0.000    1.981    1.981 <string>:1(<module>)
          2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'send' of '_socket.socket' objects}
       24/2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 brine.py:202(_dump)
       12/2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 brine.py:179(_dump_tuple)
         10    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 brine.py:106(_dump_int)
       10/2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 brine.py:360(dumpable)
          2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 protocol.py:220(_send)
          2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 protocol.py:227(_send_request)
          2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 channel.py:56(send)
          2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 <string>:531(write)
          2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 stream.py:173(write)
          2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 brine.py:332(dump)
       14/8    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 brine.py:369(<genexpr>)
          5    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'pack' of 'Struct' objects}
          2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 protocol.py:438(_async_request)
          2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 brine.py:150(_dump_str)
        6/2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {all}
          2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 protocol.py:241(_box)
         24    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'get' of 'dict' objects}
          2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'join' of 'str' objects}
          2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 brine.py:173(_dump_long)
          2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'acquire' of 'thread.lock' objects}
          2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {next}
          4    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 compat.py:17(BYTES_LITERAL)
          2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'release' of 'thread.lock' objects}
          1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
```

I am trying to makes sense of this to see where it is getting slowed down. The only difference that I really see is that the first call for the function has a different totime.

Does anyone have a better code analyzer that I could use?

Let me know if there is anything else you might need.

Comment: How big is the list of processes in your example?

Comment: Your profiling output indicates that you don't have single big call which consumes all the time so likely what is time consuming is a huge number of relatively fast function calls. I'd sort the profiling output by "cumtime" which might give you some more hints. You can try to redirect the output to a script to rule out the possibility that your terminal slows down script execution due to the amount of output. And last but not least the first example uses a lot of `process.get_process_number()` calls. Try replacing them with a static number to see if that helps your performance.

Comment: Is the posted cProcess output cut off for type 1?

Answer (score 0):

You might wanna try building a look up table of "tab strings".

Instead of:

```
output_string += ('\t' * indent_number)
```

Try:

```
output_string += indent_string[ident_number]
```

Obviously this needs some logic to only prepopulate the array up to a certain level and keep dynamically building if it goes beyond. But quick hack should give you an idea if this is your problem.